# Turn a str into a reasonable list python beginner

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to separate a string into a list that make sense
for exampia, in order to count the items on the list.
for example: str - "tomatoes,eggs,milk"
and result: lst = ['tomatoes', 'eggs', 'milk']

the code I wrote was:

```
def separate_groceries(str):
    lst = [1, 2, 3] # really limiting the len of str, i need it to be able to recive each str
    p = 0
    for i in str:
        pos = str.find(',')
        item = str[:pos]
        lst[p] = (item)
        p = p + 1
        str = str[pos+1:]
    return lst
str = "tomatoes,milk,eggs"
res = separate_groceries(str)
print(res)
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: If all you need is to be able to count the (comma-separated) items in the string, You could just use str.count(),  
`>>> a = "tomatoes,milk,eggs"  `
`>>> a.count(',')`
`2`
If you do need the string split into a list based on comma as a separator, You can use
`>>> a.split(',')`
`['tomatoes', 'milk', 'eggs']`

Comment: When learning Python, one of the most important things is to become familiar with the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Whenever you are looking for a way to do something, make it a habit to check the standard library documentation. Chances are that something in there will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stimer,

Like Niranjan Nagaraju said, what you may only need is:

```py
groceries_list = "tomatoes,milk,eggs"
res = groceries_list.split(',')
print(res)
```

You may find more information about the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) string method in the official Python documentation.